# Why does the Title in my UIButton misalign vertically in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios8

I have a UIButton created in a Storyboard. It has no special constraints / insets or anything. The only changes in code to it are :

```
[btn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"]];
[btn setTitle:@"Done"];
```

[image]

However, the button seems to be middled up whenever I use it in Autolayout :

[image]

The only way I could get it back was when I changed the background image to something else, like in :

[image]

So there seems to be something rather messed up with the Background image. However, I don't get why it doesn't work badly in pre-iOS8 then. Also, when I changed the insets :

```
self.closeButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Then I got the content inside the Button again. But now, the iOS-7 button was misaligned. Can someone help me out over here?

Comment: How big is your background image? Try setting the background image and name in the storyboard instead of in code.

Comment: It is double the size of the button.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS bug, fixed in iOS 8.1